# How do I format a number with commas using FastFormat?

Tags: c++, string-formatting, number-formatting, separator, fastformat

How do I format a number with commas for thousand separators using [FastFormat](http://www.fastformat.org/) library?

For example,

```
7800 -> 7,800
5100100 -> 5,100,100
```

Comment: Wild guess: try calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` near the top of your program, and see if that helps.  This is how it would be done with normal C or C++ IO.

Comment: Do you want to do thousands, or according to your locale?

Comment: @dcw: Thousands would be fine.  I do not have to worry about localization issues.